# Proving convergence in L1 of a sequence of functions given by integrals

Tags: convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

I am required to prove that $x\mapsto\int_x^{x+1/n} n f(y)dy$ converges in the $L^1$ sense to $f$, knowing that $f\in L^1$.

My current attempt is: after a variable change, I've rewritten $x\mapsto\int_x^{x+1/n} n f(y)dy$ as $x\mapsto\int_0^{1} f(x+y/n)dy$, which enables me to verify that indeed $x\mapsto\int_x^{x+1/n} n f(y)dy$ converges pointwise to $f$. After that, I've tried to find a dominating function in $L^1$ for $x\mapsto\int_x^{x+1/n} n f(y)dy$ in order to use the Dominated Convergence Theorem, but I didn't succeed in finding such a function.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Dominated convergence won't work here, in general there is no dominating function. The pointwise convergence is actually a much deeper result than convergence in norm, but I don't see how it helps establish convergence in norm. Hint: Let $\epsilon>0$. Pick a continuous function $g$ with compact support so $||f-g||_1<\epsilon$.

Comment: Since $f$ is not necessarily continuous in $x$, you can't say that $\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} f(x + \frac y n) = f(x)$ (which you seem to do), therefore your change of variables does not help here.

Comment: Also, note that you may have convergence in $L^1$ without pointwise convergence!

Comment: Thank your for your answers, but I didn't get your hint, David.

Comment: @gpr1 The idea is to prove the claim first for a dense subset (e.g. continuous functions with compact support) and then extend it to $L^1$-functions by approximation.